# Is there any difference between Log() and Log(LogLevel) from design perspective?

Tags: api, log4net

I've been thinking recently that is there any real difference between Log() and Log(LogLevel) from design's perspective?

For example, in log4net, the ILog interface is designed as follows.

```
// Design A 
public interface ILog
{
    /* Log a message object */
    void Debug(object message);
    void Info(object message);
    void Warn(object message);
    void Error(object message);
    void Fatal(object message);

    // ... ignore more members
}
```

But I think it is equivalent to be designed like this.

```
// Design B
public enum LogLevel
{
    Debug,
    Info,
    Warn,
    Error,
    Fatal
}

public interface ILog
{
    /* Log a message object */
    void Log(LogLevel level, object message);

    // ... ignore more members
}
```

Then why log4net not using design B? Any particular reason?

One reason I could think of is that design A reduces code noise for the caller to specify something like LogLevel.Info every time.

But design B could also have one benefit that we can change message severity within one call. e.g. logger.Log(some_bool_condition ? LogLevel.Warning : LogLevel.Error). But of course, we can create a wrapper to do something similar with design A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, both methods are accessible from the `ILog` since it derives from `ILoggerWrapper`. From there you can get a ILogger that lets you call the methods directly as the method B you are describing:

```
void Log(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, object message, Exception exception);
void Log(LoggingEvent logEvent);
```

So having the `ILog` mainly reduces code noise, and just calls the logger as expected behind the scenes:

```
// log4net.Core.LogImpl
public virtual void Info(object message)
{
    this.Logger.Log(LogImpl.ThisDeclaringType, this.m_levelInfo, message, null);
}
```

---

Obviously there is some room for different interpretations here, but here is why I think it is preferable to have the Debug/Info/Warn/Error/Fatal methods instead of a generic Log(level) one. By forcing your code to use one method, the library forces it to assert at the time of writing how important the information is in the scope of your app.

If you could just defer the level to some higher hierarchy, you would just say "oh, let the callers decide how much they want to hear from my component". But they cannot know whether something is important or not to your component. Your code shapes what information is needed; it the app user doesn't want to hear about it let him silence your logger through configuration, but only your code knows whether an absent SQL server is cause for alarm or just some minor nuisance (from a recent dev, where a DB server could disappear without problems for my component *as long as* it had answered once in the past).

Comment: Thanks @samy! By caller, I mean the component who calls the log function as you mentioned. So from the component's perspective, is there any real difference? I feel the component calling logger.Error("something") is equivalent to logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "something"), right?

Comment: That's what happens in the code, but as I was saying in the second part there is a conscious decision being made when you call Log.Error(...); you are saying "this is important".